# How do I conditional format a table in Google Sheets based on two other cell values?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

In the scenario below, the table contains random integer values.
I want to use conditional formatting in order to highlight the values in the table between the specified min and max values.
While I could hard-code 2 and 15, those are subject to change, and I'm primarily looking for a way to adjust the format rules so that they are reading the values in `A2` and `B2`, not 2 and 15.

[image: Example sheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following formula under conditional formatting:

```
=AND(C5<$B$2,C5>$A$2)
```

[image]

*(Adjust ranges to your needs)*

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.